# Get content text when catching error in RxJs

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, observable

My nodejs server send an error message with status 401:
[image: status]
[image]

With this code:

```
res.status(401).send('Invalid user or password '+info);
```

In the client code, i want to get the content text. I try this:

```
   ...
   return this.apiService.post(params)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(err: any) {
   console.log('sever error:', err);
   return Observable.throw(err || 'backend server error');
}
```

but the error message is not "Invalid user or password" it's:

> Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL:
>   ip_address/auth/login

how to get the content text when i catch the error (another status code ? another method to send the response ?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server response you are looking for is in `err._body`

```
...
return this.apiService.post(params)
     .map(res => res.json())
     // Use fat arrow for error handler also
     .catch(e => this.handleError(e));
}
private handleError(err: any) {
   console.log('sever error:', err._body);
   return Observable.throw(err || 'backend server error');
}
```

Tested it in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTTP client emits an error due to a server response, the error instance will contain `status` and `statusText` properties and the error response's content can be obtained using the `text` method (as with successful responses, error response content can be accessed using the `text` or `json` methods):

```
private handleError(err: any) {
  if (err.status) {
    console.log("status = " + err.status);
    console.log("statusText = " + err.statusText);
    console.log("text = " + err.text());
  } else {
    console.log('sever error:', err);
  }
  return Observable.throw(err || 'backend server error');
}
```